# Why am I unable to log in with my seed user C#, migration seed, Identity, core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I have added a seed user to my database. Still I am unable to log in with this user. Maybe it is the hashed password that is at fault or maybe I am totally missunderstanding the use of the IdentityUser class. I'm unsure really so any help is appreciated.

I have added the seed code into the generated Migrationsclass with the name Initial through `Add-Migration Initial`-command, at the bottom of the Up() method.

```
var hasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser();
var pass = hasher.HashPassword(user, "Holliday1!");

migrationBuilder.InsertData(
    table: "AspNetUsers",
    columns: new[] { "Id", "UserName", "Email", "PasswordHash", "EmailConfirmed", "PhoneNumberConfirmed", "TwoFactorEnabled", "LockoutEnabled", "AccessFailedCount" },
    values: new object[] { user.Id, "Admin@istrator.com", "Admin@istrator.com", pass, true, true, false, false, 0 },
    schema: null);
```

The whole class looks like this (very shortened ofcourse //):

```
public partial class Initial : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUsers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
            });

        //migrationBuilder.CreateTable("AspNetRoleClaims"...);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateTable("AspNetUserClaims"...);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateTable("AspNetUserLogins" ...);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateTable("AspNetUserRoles"...);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateTable("AspNetUserTokens"...);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(...)

        //User and role seeds
        var role1 = new IdentityRole();
        var roleId1 = role1.Id;

        var role2 = new IdentityRole();
        var roleId2 = role2.Id;

        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: new[] { "Id", "Name" },
            values: new object[,] { { roleId1, "Användare" }, { roleId2, "Administratör" } });

        var hasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
        var user = new IdentityUser();
        var pass = hasher.HashPassword(user, "Holliday1!");

        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            columns: new[] { "Id", "UserName", "Email", "PasswordHash", "EmailConfirmed", "PhoneNumberConfirmed", "TwoFactorEnabled", "LockoutEnabled", "AccessFailedCount" },
            values: new object[] { user.Id, "Admin@istrator.com", "Admin@istrator.com", pass, true, true, false, false, 0 },
            schema: null);

        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            columns: new [] {"UserId", "RoleId"},
            values: new object[] { user.Id, roleId2}
            );
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        //migrationBuilder.Drop(...) drops all tables
    }
}
```

The database is SQLLite and the user is in the db-file with generated ID and hashed password. When creating a user using the registration-page I get a different formated hashed password, which is why I am unsure if the hash that I do for my seed user is correct.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So the question is about *password migration*, not login? Or about seeding users? To seed users use `UserManager.CreateAsync`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the end result is that I should be able to login with my seeded user. I believe I have successfully seeded my user because it is shown in the db. And I am unsure if it is the passwordhashing that is the problem, though I am guessing it is :)

Comment: Why did you use *that* instead of `UserManager.CreateAsync`in the first place? Have you tried using `CreateAsync` ?

Comment: I have not yet tried usermanager. I wanted to try something else and would like this to work, but maybe that is impossible? according to this link it is an option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#manual-migration-customization @PanagiotisKanavos